# Is it possible to "unmerge" a merge commit by simply removing one of the parent pointers?

Tags: git

I would like to "unmerge" branch "A" from branch "B".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4GOu.png]

In the above image, that would mean simply removing the dotted line between commit "095195e" and "A".

I do not want to use revert, because I may later merge branch "B" back into branch "A" and I would have to revert the revert.

Also, say these two branches continue on, and A is merged into B several more times. Would there be a way to use this "unmerge" operation to remove all merges of A into B.

Thanks

Comment: Good image, did you use https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/?

Comment: Yes, it has really helped me to understand how git works a lot better!

Answer (score 3):

Can you just remove a parent from a revision? Nope. It would require a rewrite of the history of branch B:

```
git checkout e137e9b # go back to the revision before A was merged into B
git cherry-pick B~2..B # apply all changes past the point where the branches where merged
# if everything looks fine, move B pointer
git branch -f B
git checkout B
```

Now A and B are separate

The same thing can be achieved with rebase:

```
git rebase --onto e137e9b B~2 B
```

But it's not as useful in terms of explaining what's going on (exactly the same that I did on my first recipe).

Comment: I always forget you can cherry-pick a range of commits. Very handy. Nice solution.

Comment: It can be down with rebase too.... only that it's a little less obvious:

Comment: Curious as to the "why" you can't remove a parent from the merge node? On the surface it looks like it would be very simple to just remove one of the parents from a merge to give the branch the history that you are looking for.

Comment: And what would the _tree_ be like for that new revision object, if I may ask?

Comment: The thing is that if you want to remove one parent from a revision that has only one other parent, it makes sense to think that the revision you end up with is actually just the previous revision..... hence, no point in keeping that revision object in your branch history. If you were talking about removing a parent from a revision that has 3 parents, then we would be talking business and I would be telling you to try to merge the other 2 branches (and it would still be rewriting history...) but in this case, you just want to go back to the previous revision and replay the revisions after merge

Comment: ... unless you had added some code on the merge _itself_ that you might want to keep.... but we are talking about a corner case then.

Comment: Ok yes this makes sense to me now!

Comment: Also for part two of my  question. It seems like this solution you would have to run once for each merge if there were multiple merges from branch A into B .

Comment: I would then use the first recipe that I did (not the one with rebase) and you would be cherry-picking the revisions that are _not_ merges.... something like: `git cherry-pick merge1..merge2~1; git cherry-pick merge2..merge3~1; ` and so on

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this does not work:

1) The parent refs go into the calculation of the commit's hashcode. So you would Rewrite the history which is -- usually not recommended for public branches.

2) Linus once said, that Git is a stupid content tracker. This means: Git stores snapshots, not differences. In your case this means that just removing the second parent pointer would not "undo" the changes of the files associated with the merge commit.